# How to use the main window scroll bar to scroll a modal?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

The problem is that if you have a long modal, then you need to add an option to scroll it down.

However, adding a scroll bar to the modal itself would be bad for UX, cause people are intuitively used to scrolling with the scroll bar at the right end of the screen.

Several websites have this figured out, like Twitter and Product Hunt:

[image]
[image]

I can't still understand how to implement it. I have been searching for some materials online, but unfortunately couldn't find any.

If you have an idea on how it's done, please let me know.

**Update:**

Here are the styles for my current modal:

```
.modal {
    box-shadow:0 12px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index:103;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 60px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
 }
```

Comment: Show your code? Are you using bootstrap modals?

Comment: At least share the body/modal content you're working with, and it would be great to know if you've tried anything specific that didn't work.

Comment: @OmriLuzon my code would be pretty much useless in this case, since it's just a centered fixed block at this point. No i do not use bootstrap

Comment: @MichaelCoker the modal that i have works. it's just a centered fixed block with y-overflow in it. But the thing is that i want the main scroll bar to control the modal and I even conceptually have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Just don't fix the modal on the viewport. Position it. Then it'll be a scrollable element.

Comment: @Araymer won't it scroll the background content as well at the same time?

Comment: Just don't limit it's height/width, and make sure the `body` element has overflow `scroll / auto`

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. Can you link an example of the behavior you want?

Comment: @Araymer here is the link to the tweet I showed in the screenshot. If you take a look, you will see that when you scroll the main window scroll bar, it scrolls the modal but not the content in the background: https://twitter.com/ElectrekCo/status/883901337947320320

Comment: @MikeVayvala share your code. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]."* - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MichaelCoker just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar on twitter isn't the main window scrollbar - it's just a scrollbar in their modal dialog with is full screen, then they position the content of the modal dialog in the center. So when you scroll the modal, the scrollbar is on the far right, like the main window scrollbar.

To do that, I would just make your `.modal` a full screen modal with `overflow: auto`, then `absolute`ly position the content of the modal inside of it. So you're scrolling the main `.modal` window, and the scrollbar is positioned to the far right like the main window scrollbar.

```css
.modal {
  z-index: 103;

  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modalContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's the right concept. Although if you add enough content to the background, your demo you will show two side-by-side scroll bars: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZqMoM

Comment: @MikeVayvala what twitter does is add `.overlay-enabled` to `body` when a modal is open, and that sets `position: relative; overflow: hidden;` You would add that to whatever JS you're using to trigger the modal. I actually don't see a double scrollbar on my computer, but I'm on a mac. Are you? Does this fix it? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgBdXd

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.